# PHP - Reading JSON data doesn't work correctly?

Tags: php, json

So I have an piece of JSON data. Remember: I am showing piece!

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "prices" : [
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
      "price" : "15",
      "created_at" : 1460708937
    },
```

Here's my PHP, which should get price, but it doesn't work. What could be the issue? `'price'=>$prices->prices[0]->market_hash_name[$row['market_hash_name']]->price);`

Comment: post your complete json.

Comment: It's too big.. :D :D

Comment: without it i can't figure out the json.

Comment: http://www.pastebin.ca/3590939

Comment: what value you need from here????

Comment: What is `$row`? Where is the rest of your code? What doesn't work?

Comment: $row is mysql selected "string" value.

Comment: `market_hash_name` is just a string though, not an associative array.

Comment: How could I fix that code, so it would work with that JSON response? I had different JSON response before so it was working, but had to change it.

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code for us to be able to truly help. From the bit of code you pasted, it seems like you're trying to match a `prices` object using `market_hash_name[$row['market_hash_name']]` before obtaining the price from that matched object. You've selected the 1st object in the array (position 0) already with `prices[0] `. Try `$prices->prices[0]->price` and adjust the array key 0 to select others.

Comment: There's nothing more basically.. Just matching other things.. I want to match example $name = "Swag"; from that json. and get it's price.

Comment: give the value of `$prices`, `$row['market_hash_name']`.

Comment: $prices is that json output.. that $row example is: AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)

Comment: okey you need to use `foreach` and check for `market_hasah_name` and get the `price`.

Comment: Maybe you could help me out with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over your *prices* to find the matching *market_hash_name* using `$row['market_hash_name']`. Then you can extract the *price* from that matching object.

I tried to keep your code as close to the same as possible.

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `items`');
$prices2 = file_get_contents('cache/SuiPrices.json');
$prices2 = json_decode($prices);
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $price = null;
    foreach($prices2->prices as $data) {
        if($row['market_hash_name'] == $data->market_hash_name) {
            $price = (float) $data->price;

            break;
        }
    }

    $array['items'][] = array(
        'img' => 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'.$row['img'].'/200fx200',
         'name' => $row['market_hash_name'],
         'assetid' => $row['assetid'],
         'price' => $price
    }
}

exit(json_encode($array));
```

Comment: Your code is perfect! But I don't get it, why it doesn't get the price from that file :/

Comment: Try to debug it by adding `echo` statements. For instance, use `echo $row['market_hash_name'] . "\n";` inside the `while()` loop. Use `echo $data->market_hash_name  . "\n";` inside the `foreach()` loop. Then see if the first response matches any of the rest on your page. My code uses a 1:1 match (==) and if the _market_hash_name_ isn't exactly the same, it won't match and `$price` will remain `null`.

Comment: Problem seems to be here just found out: ($row['market_hash_name'] == $data->market_hash_name)

Comment: Mind sharing with us exactly why the `==` comparison wasn't working? Did you use `trim()` to remove extraneous whitespace? Obviously there were no exact matches but it'd be nice to know how you modified `$row['market_hash_name']` or `$data->market_hash_name` to match. You can also use `stripos($data->market_hash_name, $row['market_hash_name']) !== FALSE` instead of `$row['market_hash_name'] == $data->market_hash_name` to do a case-insensitive search that is less strict.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you dont have *price* under *market_hash_name* node.
This should do the trick:

```
//the second parameter (true) says that the function should return an array
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true); 
echo $data['prices'][0]['price'];
```

**Important:** This is only an example using the given json string part. You must index the nodes yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout the answer:**

Online link: [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/s0uNO)

> The main JSON data is too big and not run in any web server like
>   sandbox or 3v41.

There is the portion of the `json`.

```
$market_hash_name = 'AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)';

$json = '{
  "status" : "success",
  "prices" : [
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
      "price" : "15",
      "created_at" : 1460708937
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
      "price" : "41.4",
      "created_at" : 1460708934
    }
    ]
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($arr['prices'] as $key => $val){
    if($val['market_hash_name'] == $market_hash_name){
        echo $val['price']; //15
    }   
}
```

Comment: sure, try and let me know.

Comment: I added the pastebin here, should I put it to main post?

Comment: your json is too large for PHP processing. This code is running fine on my local server. Try to get the json as optimized.